# SwiftUI Button cannot be clicked on its whole area

Tags: swift, swiftui

I built a custom Button.
My problem is, that it can be only clicked on the Text Elements not on the whole area of the Button.
What's going wrong, how can I solve this?

```
struct MyButton: View {
  
  var body: some View
  { Button( action:{ print("pressed") })
  { HStack {
      VStack(alignment: .leading){
        Text("Tomorrow").font(.caption)
        Text("23.5.22 KW 23")
      }
      Spacer()
    }
  }
  .padding([.horizontal],4.0)
  .padding([.vertical],2.0)
  .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.red))
  .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
  .padding([.horizontal],8.0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the padding to the HStack, not the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, only the parts of the view that actually render something are tappable. You need to add a `.contentShape(Rectangle())` modifier to your `Button` to make the entire area interactive.

Comment: This worked for me when added to the `Label` parameter (of type `View`) on my `NavigationLink` but not when added to the 'NavigationLink' itself.